# Why is quit command in runmqsc not working?

Tags: command-line, ibm-mq

I have MQ 7.5 installed on a ubuntu machine.
From the terminal I can run the `runmqsc` command this takes me into a shell.

[image]

I run a few commands,

[image]

then when I try to exit `runmqsc` by typing `quit`, i get a error message.

[image]

Only `end` seems to work.

[image]

**Why is this happening?** Have I changed some setting inadvertently?

Update 1:
Below is the output of the dspmqver command.

```
user1@ubuntuvm-5:~$ /opt/mqm/bin/dspmqver
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.5.0.2
Level:       p750-002-130704
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 4.4.0-96-generic
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:    
Primary:     No
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 750
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quit` and `exit` were added to `runmqsc` at V8.0. Prior to that release there was only `end`.

See [Knowledge Center: runmqsc (V8.0.0)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083460_.htm) and [IBM Tech note: New features added to the runmqsc command in IBM MQ Version 8.0](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045974).

Comment: This was working until yesterday. The only change I made was remove libre office packages from Ubuntu. Didn’t mention it because I did not think it was relevant.

Comment: I will restore VM from backup and check.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what FixPack of V7.5 you are on (before and after restore of back up). I'm wondering whether this V8 feature was retrofitted to a V7.5 Fix Pack.

Comment: @moraghughson I have added the output of dspmqver to my question.

Comment: @Ajay I confirmed what Morag stated that even in the latest 7.5.0.8, `quit` and `exit` are not supported, only `end`.  I was not aware that `quit` and `exit` were added at v8+ until reading this answer. I confirmed on 8.0.0.6 I see both along with `end`.  I have noticed other questions you have posted where you also use v8, is it possible you are confusing the usage on one of those? I would suggest just using `end` since it is consistent and supported in **all** versions of MQ past and present.

Comment: @JoshMc, I started using 'end' since it is consistent with all version.